# Move code from a branch of repoA to another repository repoB

Tags: git, gerrit

Keeping the git history preserved, how do I move code from a particular branch of repoA to another repository repoB?

Comment: Add a new remote and push there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pull/push from multiple remote locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations)

Answer (score 0):

1. On `repoA` checkout the branch you want to move to `repoB`
2. Add `repoB` as a remote: `git remote add repoB https://github.com/repo/repoB.git`
3. Push your current branch to the remote: `git push repoB`

Note that in step 2 the 'remote' repo can actually be local (i.e. on your local box), e.g. `git remote add repoB /home/repos/repoB/.git`